# VBA how to use for loop with step 3 with a counter only augmenting with one at a time

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I want to program an augmentation of a number every three years. I know you can use a for loop with step 3. The problem is I need to have my counter augment with one. 
In an example:
The allowance of a kid dubbels every three years. I need to program the augmentation until a certain age. In the result something like this has to show up:
at age 5 the allowance is 10
at age 6 the allowance is 10
at age 7 the allowance is 10
at age 8 the allowance is 20
at age 9 the allowance is 20
at age 10 the allowance is 20
I would use my counter of the for loop for the age but that only gives me 5 and 8 in this cause.

I hope my question is understandable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use some math ?

Comment: Or `Step 3` but set three values within each iteration?

Comment: @TimWilliams could you give me an example?

Comment: @YowE3K: do you mean using a new loop to do the augmentation?

Comment: You haven't shown your existing code, so I don't know whether it is a "new" loop or not.  Ohh - perhaps you meant do you need to have an internal loop to set three values.  If so, that is up to you - personally I wouldn't bother, I would just write the statement three times, but other people prefer to write it as a loop even though it is only three iterations.

Comment: And a simple formula would be `10 * (2 ^ Int((age - 5) / 3))` (assuming age is never less than 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@YowE3K: thanks for the tip, with an extra for loop for the 3 values it worked! I solved it this way: 
`For intteller = 5 To intleeftijd Step 3 
    For intteller2 = 1 To 3 
    strresultaat = strresultaat & "Op " & intteller + intteller2 - 1 & "jaar bedraagt jouw zakgeld " & sngzakgeld & vbCrLf 
    Next intteller2 
sngzakgeld = sngzakgeld * 2 
Next intteller`